# Dragging marker is not refreshing address

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

In fallowing code `Getaddress` function will call when marked `dragend` event happens

```
    Getaddress(LastLat, LastLng , marker,source){
        this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+LastLat+ ','+LastLng )
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(this.data); //json output
                this.data = data.results[0].formatted_address;
              console.log(this.data); //Right address
                this.Origin=" ";
                this.Origin=this.data;
              }
});
```

and in html:

```
<ion-item> <ion-label >Origin</ion-label> <ion-input type="text" value={{Origin}}></ion-input> </ion-item>
```

when marker dragend Right address will be shown on console log. but in `input item` it only shows first place of maker and if I click on `input item` it will change the last address or location that marker mentions. I changed `input item` to Label but it is not effective.

**Update 1 dragend event :**

```
lastLatLng(marker,source){
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () =>{ 
      this.LastLat= marker.position.lat();
      this.LastLng= marker.position.lng();
      this.Getaddress(this.LastLat,this.LastLng, marker,source);    
    });
    }
```

Comment: Updated answer.. hope it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *bind* the value to the variable. Your code is setting the `value` attribute.

Try:

```
<ion-item> <ion-label >Origin</ion-label> <ion-input type="text" [value]="Origin"></ion-input> </ion-item>
```

Check Angular template syntax [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)

UPDATE:

Create a callback function:

```
setOriginAddress(data:any){
   this.data = data.results[0].formatted_address;
              console.log(this.data); //Right address
                this.Origin=" ";
                this.Origin=this.data;
}
```

//Create a similar callback for dragevent without setting this.Origin.

```
lastLatLng(marker,source){
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () =>{ 
      this.LastLat= marker.position.lat();
      this.LastLng= marker.position.lng();
      this.Getaddress(this.LastLat,this.LastLng, marker,source,this.setOriginAddress.bind(this));    
    });
    }
```

GetAddress

```
Getaddress(LastLat, LastLng , marker,source,callbackFn){
        this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+LastLat+ ','+LastLng )
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(callbackFn);
```

Comment: tnx, But still the same. the interesting thing is that I add 2 marker in a one page the second one is dowing well but first one no, and if I remover 2nd marker it will nothing change.

Comment: can you add the complete function of dragend event?

Comment: Lastlatlng method was added to main question.

Comment: I want to show firist marker "Origin" as i asked in main question.

Comment: Ok.. You will have to avoid setting Origin in GetAddress.The value is getting reset to second address. Maybe send a callback to GetAddress for origin address and dragevent.